# Spring boot cache No cache could be resolved for Builder

Tags: caching, spring-boot

According to [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html), the simplest configuration to use cache in spring boot is using CacheManager (an cache Map would be initialized in this class):

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheService extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager concurrentMapCacheManager() {
        ConcurrentMapCacheManager cmcm = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
        return cmcm;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager guavaCacheManager() {
        GuavaCacheManager gcm = new GuavaCacheManager();
        return gcm;
    }
}
```

and in `serviceImpl.java`:

```
 @Cacheable(cacheManager="guavaCacheManager")
 @Override
 public List<RoleVO> getDataForCreateNewOperator() {
  ...
 }
```

But it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No cache could be resolved for 'Builder[public java.util.List getDataForCreateNewOperator()] caches=[] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='guavaCacheManager' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'' using resolver 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheResolver@38466d10'. At least one cache should be provided per cache operation.
```

EDIT:
if I assign a cacheName in cacheManager, and use it in the advised method, the exception is gone. But all methods in the bean would be cached, while I only assigned `@Cacheable` on one method.

Comment: Did you tried something like this: @Cacheable(cacheNames = "cache-name") on your repository method?

Comment: @Afridi yes I tried, and that works. But not dynamic one, which should also work too. Besides, using cacheName although the exception is gone, but it makes the whole class cacheable, not only the method.

Answer (score 8):

I am using Ehcache and i had the same issue because i had two different names for cache and Cacheable.

Please make you use same name for cache and Cacheable.

```
@Cacheable("codetable")
    <cache name="codetable"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, Fixed by giving a proper name for cache

```
@Cacheable(value = "testCache")
```

some times, `@Cacheable` is not enough.

Comment: This was the solution for my Redis cache